# Pasar texto del botón a la callback llamada cuando es presionado

Tags: python, tkinter

Necesito obtener el texto dentro del botón presionado, ya que no puedo saber cual se presionó y además están generados dinámicamente en un ciclo.

Intente con `StringVar` pero se obtiene solo el del ultimo indice, necesito saber que botón se presiono o saber el texto dentro del que se presiono.

Este es mí código:

```
def showStock():
  aShowS=Toplevel()
  aShowS.geometry("400x300")
  aShowS.title("Ver Stock")
  posX=30
  posY=30
  lista=dbManage.getData("P")
  global botonData
  botonData=StringVar()
  for k in range(0,len(lista)):
    dicc=lista[k]
    dialog="ID: "+dicc["ID"]+" | Cepa: "+dicc["Cepa"]+" |Banco:"+dicc["Banco"]
    label = Label(aShowS, text=dialog).place(x=posX,y=posY)
    botonData="Ver datos de "+dicc["Cepa"]
    boton=Button(aShowS,text=botonData, command=dbViewData,bg="crimson",width=12,height=2).place(x=80,y=posY+20)
```

Comment: Gracias! Siempr es bueno saber mas sobre uno de mis lenguajes favoritos, resulta que solo me lo pasaron superficialmente ya que estudio la carrera de ingenieria en informatica y solo me pasan programacion por fuera sl2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple de resolver el problema es usar [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Un ejemplo reproducible pasando el texto del botón:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk



def db_view_data(texto):
    print(texto)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")


for n in range(10):
    texto = str(n)
    tk.Button(root, text=texto, command=partial(db_view_data, texto)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Puedes pasar los argumentos que quieras, incluso la propia instancia del botón si mantienes una referencia al mismo mediante una variable y usas el método `configure` tras la sustanciación.

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk



def db_view_data(boton):
    print(boton["text"])


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")


for n in range(10):
    texto = str(n)
    boton = tk.Button(root, text=texto)
    boton.configure(command=partial(db_view_data, boton))
    boton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Unas cuantas observaciones sobre el código independientes al problema en sí:

- Si quieres mantener una referencia al widget no llames al método `place/pack/grid` en la misma línea en la que instancias el widget:

  ```
  label = Label(aShowS, text=dialog).place(x=posX,y=posY)
  ```

  En este caso la variable `lavel` está asociada al retorno de `place`, que es `None`, por lo que es totalmente inútil. Si no necesitas la referencia a la instancia del widget simplemente haz:

  ```
  Label(aShowS, text=dialog).place(x=posX,y=posY)
  ```

  Si la necesitas, separa la llamada al método de la instanciación:

  ```
  label = Label(aShowS, text=dialog)
  label.place(x=posX, y=posY)
  ```
- Evita concatenar cadenas, al ser inmutables cada vez que concatenas se crea un nuevo objeto temporal, que luego ha de ser eliminado por el recolector de basura además. Usa `str.join` o `str.format` o literales de cadena formateados (Python >= 3.6) siempre que tengas que concatenar más de dos cadenas:

  ```
  dialog = f'ID: {dicc["ID"]} | Cepa: {dicc["Cepa"]} | Banco:{dicc["Banco"]}'
  ```

  o en Python <= 3.6:

  ```
  dialog = 'ID: {} | Cepa: {} | Banco:{}'.format(dicc["ID"], dicc["Cepa"], dicc["Banco"])
  ```
- No iteres sobre una lista usando `range` e indexado a no ser que sea estrictamente necesario, es ineficiente y poco "pitónico". Usa un `for in` en su lugar: `for dicc in lista`. Si necesitas el índice usa `enumerate`, por ejemplo: `for indice, dicc in enumerate(lista):`
- No lo muestras en tu código, pero no debes importar mediante `from tkinter import *`  a no ser que esté plenamente justificado (generalmente solapar espacios de nombres de forma intencionada). Esta forma de importar es una mala práctica en general, entre otras cosas porque puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin necesidad, dificulta la legibilidad del código y puede solapar nombres ya definidos en el espacio de nombres actual, causando errores. Puedes importar de varias formas:

  ```
  from tkinter import Label, Button, Tk
  ```

  o:

  ```
  import tkinter as tk
  ```
- Por último, te recomiendo mirarte las convenciones de estilo de código definidas en [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). En especial te recomiendo seguir las convenciones para nombrar variables/funciones/clases... y sobre todo, usa siempre 4 espacios para identar.

Teniendo lo anterior en cuenta y que falta contexto, el código podría quedar así:

```
import tkinter as tk


def show_stock():
    stock_screen = tk.Toplevel()
    stock_screen.geometry("400x300")
    stock_screen.title("Ver Stock")

    pos_x = 30
    pos_y = 30
    lista = dbManage.getData("P")

    for dicc in lista:
        dialog = f'ID: {dicc["ID"]} | Cepa: {dicc["Cepa"]} | Banco:{dicc["Banco"]}'
        tk.Label(stock_screen, text=dialog).place(x=pos_x, y=pos_y)
        boton_text = f'Ver datos de {dicc["Cepa"]}'
        tk.Button(stock_screen, text=boton_text, partial(db_view_data, boton_text),
                  bg="crimson", width=12, height=2).place(x=80, y=pos_y + 20)
```